# How to enable debug messages for pam_systemd_home.so?

Tags: systemd, pam, debugging

The manual for `pam_systemd_home` states that debug messages can be enabled with `debug=yes`, but they don't state *where* to put it.

I tried adding the options to the relevant lines in `pam.d/system-auth`, but it seems to cause a syntax error and disabled `sudo`: I needed `su` to allow me to edit the files and revert the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `debug` on the lines where `pam_systemd_home` is used. As an example :

```
-session  optional   pam_systemd_home.so debug
```